# Code::Blocks, static code analysis included (cppcheck)?

Tags: static-analysis, codeblocks, cppcheck

The [Cppcheck website](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net) tells me that Code::Blocks has Cppcheck built in. The [Wikipedia page on IDEs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments) tells me that Code::Blocks has an integrated static code analysis (that would be Cppcheck then, wouldn't it?).

Where can I find it? Looked through all menus and plugins and documentation that I could find, but nothing....

Comment: It's under the `Plugins` menu for me...  Perhaps when you were installing Code::Blocks you opted out of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible you opted-out of the plugins when you were first installing Code::Blocks.  If this is the case, you might need to install it manually.

Under the "Plugins" menu, go to "Manage plugins..." and select "Install new."  The plugin file is available here: http://www.2shared.com/file/-EZxdUJG/CppCheck-11.htm

Comment: Yeah, I didn't installed it. But it's actually Opt-In - so you only get if you want it.